# What's the point of the map in MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

What is the point of map?  For example, instead of the below, why not just use:  `reducer = (accum, x) => accum + (x + 2)`?

Or with mapper and reducer separate:

```
mapper = (x) => x + 2
reducer = (accum, y) => accum + y
```

So:

```
//  x     y     
//  0     2
//  1     3

[0, 1].map(mapper).reduce(reducer, 0) // result == 5
```

Are there examples in "big data technologies" like Hadoop, where moving all the functionality into the reducer is undesirable / incurs some penalty that's avoided by having a separate mapper.

I can think of examples where knowing the initial value is actually required in the `reducer`; making the use of a "purely map" `mapper` function impossible or at least pointless as you'd have to be mapping to a value that contains the initial value, e.g. from `mapper`, returning a tuple containing the initial value so that `reducer` can access it:

```
mapper = (x) => [x, lookupValue1[x] * lookupValue2[x]]
reducer = (accum, y) => { accum[y[0]] = y[1]; return accum; }

//  x          y
//  'alex'    ['alex',  -41]
//  'chris'   ['chris', 102]
['alex', 'chris'].map(mapper).reduce(reducer, {})

// result = { 'alex': -41, 'chris': 102 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think `MapReduce` as a design pattern to efficiently process "suitable" data. By this, I mean to say two things:

1) MapReduce is not the efficient way to process all "type" of data. There can be certain type of data and processing steps; which can leverage `HDFS` and distributed processing. `MapReduce` is just a tool in that league which is best suited with certain algorithm.

2) Not all algorithm are suitable for `mapreduce`. Because its a design pattern, it best suits for certain algorithms which are inline with a certain design. That is why `mapreduce` core library allow you to skip `mapper` (using identity Mapping) or `reducer` (just by setting number of reducer as zero). You are allowed to skip one one more phases of `mapreduce` according to your need.

Keeping these two point in center, if you understand how `map-combine - sort + shuffle - reduce` works; it can help you to implement an algorithm which is more efficient than using any other tool. At the same time, if your data and algorithm is really not a 'fit' to mapreduce, you could end up with a highly inefficient `mapreduce` program.

If you wish to research on significance of mapper in `mapreduce`, just study the `wordcount` program example (comes bundled with `mapreduce`). Try implementing it with/without `mapper` (or `reducer` or `mapreduce` altogether) and benchmark the performance. I hope you would find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, I suggest you to start with very basics of MR without jumping to a conclusion.

Please follow the following link. 
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/

```
Just to provide some pointers. 
 1. Reducer canot read directly from HDFS, it has to read data from Mappers. 
 2. One has to minimise data trasfer from Mapper to reducer hence choice of combiner. 
 3. Less data sent from mapper to reducer, faster is the job, so we try to filter as early as possible.
 4.  The chances that all the keys will be read by the same mapper are very low, hence to reduce data needs to be sent to the reducer. 
 5. Alway imagine of a 1 TB file with key1 occuring twice and located at the beginning of the file and end of file. Apply all your logics for this and will realize what MR, spark is all about.
```